# Should a contingency table be "symmetric"?

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

Im am running a fishers exact test on some data in R but im unsure of how the input contingency table should be formatted.

Option 1

```
   1  2 3  4  5 6  7
1  0  5 0 18  1 0  7
2  5  2 0 15  1 0  9
3  0  0 0  2  0 0  1
4 18 15 2 46 25 0 27
5  1  1 0 25 10 0  7
6  0  0 0  0  0 0  0
7  7  9 1 27  7 0 12
```

or Option 2

```
   1  2  3  4  5  7
1  0  1  0 12  0  2
2  4  1  0  6  1  5
3  0  0  0  2  0  0
4  6  9  0 23 10  9
5  1  0  0 15  5  3
7  5  4  1 18  4  6
```

The difference is, that in option 1, all occurrences of [1,2] (five in total) are in both cells they meet. In option 2 there is one occurrence of [1,2] and four occurrences of [2,1] which are listed separately. The results of those tables are very different (Option 1 is significant, Option 2 is not). Which one is the right way to go?

Comment: If there are two variables (say `v1` and `v2`) and it's the case that there are four cases where `v1=2` and `v2=1` and there is one case where `v1=1` and `v2=2`, then option 2 is the right way.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. For clarification: the rows and columns are groups that have interactions with each other. So there is one occurrence where group 1 interacts with group 2 and four occurrences where group 2 interacts with group 1 (in total 5 interactions). I want to find out if groups are more likely to interact with themselves or with others.

Comment: If your question is "if groups are more likely to interact with themselves or others", then neither is correct, as there's no point disaggregating all the possible not-self interactions (you might detect significant differences between specific non-self groups, but that's not what you're asking) - you should only have self / not-self

Comment: You mean just see how many interactions are on the diagonal and compare it to the rest? This is of course a way, but i would like to know if the results are significant which (at least to my understanding) would be possible with a fisher exact test

Comment: Fisher's exact assumes that the observations are independent. That is not the case if one observation (one pair) is listed in multiple cells. Also it is not clear how does group interacts with itself. We need a reproducible example of the data that is used to produce these tables.